# No iphone devices in Visual Studio

Tags: ios, .net, macos, visual-studio, xamarin

I have started a Xamarin.Forms projects for all three platforms (iOS, Android and UWP).

I have connected to my mac and the icon is green. I made sure that both, Mac and VS have the same versions of Xamarin.

VS for Mac versions:

[image: Mac config]

VS for Windows versions:

[image: Win config]

My Xcode version is 9.3

But I don't have the iPhones list to debug. 
[image: Debug list]

PS. When I press "Show iOS Simulator" button, it starts simulator on my Mac.

My question is: What am I missing in my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin doesn't currently work with xcode 9.3.

I had this issue yesterday. You need to remove 9.3 and install 9.2 from the apple developer website.

- un-install xcode 9.3 on mac
- install xcode 9.2 on mac
- restart mac
- in visual studio - forget mac connection, re-connect when mac back up.